# setting map boundary / edge when nowrap is engaged

Tags: leaflet, bounds

Is there any way to adjust the bounds of the map so that the right-edge of Russia doesn't appear over to the left? You can see in the image I have a MultiPolygon area overlaying Russia but the map and the overlay are split. I'd like that tiny piece of the country to be on the right if possible!

Edge of Russia on the wrong side of the map:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

If your multi polygon is the blueish area, then I am afraid you have to refactor your data in order to achieve what you want (shifting the left area onto the right, as if it were stitched back to Russia main land).

Your data (probably GeoJSON?) contains a separate polygon which longitudes are in the [-180, -120] range. Leaflet has no choice but to display it on the left of your map, independently from the `noWrap` option.

So you would need to dig into your data, and add 360 degrees longitude to every node of this polygon, so that they now sit in the range [180, 300].

Or somehow introduce a "detection" in your code that would perform the longitude addition automatically for shapes which bounds and/or center are far away (let's say in the [-180, -120] longitude range). Leaflet does not perform that operation automatically out-of-the-box.

Note: the `noWrap` option is for your Tile Layer not to load tiles outside that "central" world (in order to avoid showing multiple copies of the world). But in your case, you **want** to show a part of Russia / Siberia on an "adjacent copy of the world", so you might want to remove that option, or you will have your polygon not sitting over any basemap.

Comment: I guess my issue is the fact that there is that small part of Russia in an adjacent copy of the world map. Is there any way I can move it to the other map? Effectively shifting the viewport of the map over to the right just a little.  
  
Is it possible to decide what is the 'top,left' and 'bottom,right' of the bounding box into which I can view this map?

Comment: As for navigation/interaction, just refer to chrki's answer with map's `maxBounds` option. As for hiding Siberia from "central world" tiles and showing it on "right hand side world", you would probably be interested in [TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) plugin.

Comment: As for moving your polygon, as said in the above answer, you can either refactor your data, or try to make up a "detection" of far-west polygon that needs to be moved 360 degrees longitude East-wards (you would add 360 degrees to each longitude coordinate in the GeoJSON data).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I can think of is using the [`maxBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) property, where you would shift the default bounds slightly to the right, along with `minZoom: 1`. This won't prevent the user from seeing the world several times for a short time if zoomed out far / panning outside, as it says there:

> ... bouncing the user back when he tries to pan outside the view

```
var map = L.map('map',{ 
  maxBounds:[ [-90, -160], [90, 200] ],
  minZoom: 1
  }).setView([66.058, 189.459], 4);
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1qNopXhg7s7PcU135U6V?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this addition. I like the way this forces a bounce-back on the map when dragged. It unfortunately doesn't resolve my original question but this feature is going into my code nonetheless :)